# Angular 9 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'xxxxxx.net/api' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' hase been blocked by policy

Tags: angular9

I would like to use the function `userAPI()` to display the content of the api but it doesn't work even though I used Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

```js
this.service.userAPI().subscribe(data => console.log(data));

    httpOptions = {
     myHeaders : new HttpHeaders( { 
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' :'https://xxxxxxxx.net/api/expenseItems',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'myHeaders, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Origin, Authorization, 
     Accept, Client-Security-Token, Accept-Encoding',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer Tokenxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  })
}

    requestOptions = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: this.httpOptions.myHeaders,
    redirect: 'follow'
};
    userAPI():Observable<any>{
    return this.httpClient.get('https://xxxxxxxxxxx.net/api/expenseItems', this.requestOptions)
}
```

Comment: Have you read any of the other posts and resources about CORS? **You can't set those headers on the client**, they're response headers.

Comment: Please check your API . Mostly it has to  allow cross origin requests.

Comment: check api. What are you using for backend?

Comment: if the api dont allow cross origin requests, what's the solution to acces to the data with bearer token ?